# Advanced Aggregation: Should I disable core's aggregation?

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

I know that AdvAgg's bundler will, by default, disable core's *grouping logic*, but I'm unclear as to whether core's aggregation should be enabled or disabled (at admin/config/development/performance) for AdvAgg to be able to aggregate files in the first place.

Basically, I can't tell if AdvAgg is actually aggregating things itself (and thus core should probably be disabled under admin/config/development/performance), or if AdvAgg is taking core's aggregated files and only handling the bundling aspect of aggregation, in which case core's aggregation would need to be enabled. I suspect the former is the case, but I can find no explicit information on this.

Can anyone tell me what the general best practice here is?

Comment: In the Drupal 6 version this was true; you had to disable core in order for it to work. Luckily Drupal 7 made overriding core a lot easier so this is no longer the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I disable core's aggregation?

No; AdvAgg uses the core aggregation setting as part of its own on/off switch. If core aggregation is disabled, AdvAgg aggregation is implicitly disabled.

In fact if you do disable it, you get this helpful error in the status report:

[image]

You can tell whether or not AdvAgg is producing your files from the path - it will contain `/advagg_(css|js)/`.